Movie about Afterlife that was on Hulu in USA in early 2000s; drama
It was a serious movie, about someone who moved on to the Afterlife and what that was like.  I recall that person (I think a young man) moving across terrain, getting to a beautiful masonry wall.  This wall would open and let the "good ones" in.  Those who had been there a while would take care of the new arrivals in a catacombs-type place.  The man went to visit a God-like guy to discuss the way things were around this Afterlife Place; they went for a ride in some sort of vehicle and talked about things.  After spirits advanced, they are able to help others; one of the ways they do this is go back to that beautiful wall that parts and assist them in trying to make it across the difficult terrain in the beginning of trying to reach the Afterlife.  There may be a Life Review during this part of the movie---I do not recall that portion of the movie clearly.  Intended to be comforting in the spiritual sense, I think.  The edition I saw on Hulu was in English; main actors were white, I think.
To distinguish from other Afterlife movies---there is no war, intergalactic feeling, etc.  The only dissonance in the movie the main characters experience is over that terrain outside the beautiful wall before entering the Afterlife area.  The spirit-people who are reclining in the catacombs area who have just arrived to the Afterlife may experience some dissonance, if I remember correctly, as they adjust to their new realm.

Sounds vaguely like "What Dreams May Come", but I do not recall a wall separating places.

Thanks for posting.  It wasn't "What Dreams May Come", but that sounds like a good movie.  I would have remembered Robin Williams.
